# If you catch an exception by reference, can you modify it and rethrow?

Tags: c++, exception

Does the standard have anything to say about an exception that is caught by reference and what happens to attempts to modify it?

Consider the following code:

```
class my_exception: public std::logic_error
{
public:
    std::vector<std::string> callstack;
};

void MyFunc()
{
    try
    {
        SomethingThatThrows();
    }
    catch (my_exception & e)
    {
        e.callstack.push_back("MyFunc");
        throw;
    }
}
```

This is a contrived example, I'm not actually attempting something like this. I was just curious what would happen, based on the suggestion in another thread that exceptions should be caught by *const* reference.

Comment: boost::exception has some neat tools for this.

Comment: push_back can throw. Copy constructor of string can throw. Today I'd prefer a std::array<char, BIG_ENOUGH> what_msg inside exception. So that you can implement virtual what easily.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The exception will change.

§15.3[except.handle]/17:

> When the handler declares a non-constant object, any changes to that object will not affect the temporary
>    object that was initialized by execution of the throw-expression.
>
> When the handler declares a reference to
>   a non-constant object, any changes to the referenced object are changes to the temporary object initialized
>   when the throw-expression was executed and will have effect should that object be rethrown.

So if `my_exception` is caught outside of `MyFunc`, we'll see the `"MyFunc"` entry in the callstack (e.g. http://ideone.com/5ytqN)

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can do this.

When you rethrow the current exception using `throw;`, no copies are made:  the original temporary exception object is rethrown.  Thus, any changes you make to that object in the handler will be present in the exception object when you next catch it.